# using linq to select and change values over/under a certain threshold C#

Tags: c#, linq

As the title suggest, is there anyway of assigning all values in an array over 250 to 250 and all values under 0 to 0? I've tried using a simple if statement but since I have a foreach loop I can't assign the iteration variable.

```
int[] rgbArray = { 10, 260, -10};
 foreach (int i in rgbArray)
    {
        if (i < 0)
        {
            //do something
        }
        else if (i > 250)
        {
            //do something
        }
```

Comment: Use a `for` loop and use the index `rgbArray[i]` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `for` loop will do the job, just use the iterator as the array index.

Example:

```
int[] rgbArray = { 10, 260, -10 };
for (var i = 0; i < rgbArray.Length; i++)
{
    if (rgbArray[i] < 0)
    {
        rgbArray[i] = 0;
    }
    else if (i > 250)
    {
        rgbArray[i] = 250;
    }
}
```

If it was to be done with LINQ it'd be something like this, where I'd argue the former example is much easier to read.

```
rgbArray = rgbArray.Select(x => x < 0 ? 0 : x > 250 ? 250 : x).ToArray();
```